# Select Specified Range on Varying Sheet Names from another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a myself into a situation,
I realize I'm new here and I hope I don't make too many mistakes.

I have Workbooks with different names in a folder. I have my VBA list the paths of the .csv files.

Each Workbook has a unique name, identical to the sheet within.

Next I want to loop through the workbooks combining to a MASTER.xlsm

The data is from a OBDII Car App so the Rows Count is always unknown.

```
Range("A1").Resize(Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
  Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column).Select
```

This code above, worked when I used it in one of the varying Workbooks manually. But I'm getting a

> Run-Time error 1004 Application or Object Defined Error

when I try and implement it from the MasterWorkbook.

```
Private Sub cmd_COPYpaste()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

''''DIMMENSIONS

Dim SourceRow As Long
Dim EditRow As Long
Dim sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Const scWkbSourceName As String = "MASTER.xlsm"

Set wkbSource = Workbooks(scWkbSourceName)
Set wksSource = wkbSource.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Replace Sheet1 with the sheet name

Const wsOriginalBook As String = "MASTER.xlsm"

SourceRow = 2

''ENSURE SELECT SOURCE SHEET
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Do While Cells(SourceRow, "B").Value <> ""

FileName1 = wksSource.Range("B" & SourceRow).Value

sFile = FileName1

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)

''CREATE TABLE1 ON AWORKBOOK

Dim AWorkbook As Workbook
Set AWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

''CREATE a REFERENCE-ABLE Sheet
Dim AWorksheet As Worksheet
Set AWorksheet = AWorkbook.ActiveSheet

''SELECT DATA RANGE
```

next line is my Error

```
AWorksheet.Range("A1").Resize(Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
  Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column).Select

Selection.Copy

Windows("MASTER.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet3").Select                 'IMPORT TO SHEET
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

''CLOSE WORKBOOK W/O BEFORE SAVE
AWorkbook.Activate
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False 'Will NOT save changes
Application.EnableEvents = True

Windows("MASTER.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

'''FUTURE CODE

''GO TO NEXT FILE
SourceRow = SourceRow + 1 ' Move down 1 row for source sheet

Loop

End Sub
```

I plan on finishing the code in the future but for now I want it is to copy & paste to A1 on Sheet3 over and over.

I am stuck thinking I messed something up with the

```
''Need to CREATE a REFERENCE-ABLE Sheet
Dim AWorksheet As Worksheet
Set AWorksheet = AWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

How Can I get around not knowing the sheet name and still have full control over the sheet from another Workbook?

I thought I specified AWorkbook's Active Sheet

Column A on Master Workbook Sheet 1 has the filename and filename1 is the Full Path in Column B.

I appreciate you sticking in with me and I'd love to hear your thoughts and simplifications (props to everyone who has gotten me this far)?

Comment: Try changing `AWorksheet.Range` to `ws.Range`

Comment: Update: I changed

to

    Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
      Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column).Select 

but it's selecting the Column and Row Counts from the MASTER on the active workbook. (MASTER Sheet1 has 101 Rows and 2 Columns but I need it to do that on the Opened active workbook.

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: You do know that if your code does loop through the workbook list in column B, your paste will over write  each previous paste.

Comment: Also, get rid of `Activate` and `Select`. e.g. `ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Paste`.

Comment: @GMalc thanks. Why change AWorkbook.Range to ws.Range? I'm relatively new to VBA and yes I'm aware it will paste over top of it's self in it's current state.

Comment: Sorry you need to change it to `wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range`. When you set Set `wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)`, you set the workbook variable `ws` to the workbook file you opened. You don't need to reset it to `AWorkbook`. Also, you don't need to set the variable for `wkbSource` because `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook where you have the vba code.

Comment: @GMalc my current problem is that I'm Counting the range calculated from "ThisWorkbook" and Selecting that Range Criteria on the AWorkbook. If i use wb.sheets("Sheet1").Range I get an error because I don't have the Sheet Name correct.. (The sheet name Changes with the Workbook)

Comment: This will error out if any range.find instances don’t find the value

Answer (score 0):

you could substitute your code from:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)
```

to:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
```

with the following (explanations in comments):

```
With Workbooks.Open(sFile) ' open and referecne your current workbook
    With .Worksheets(Split(.Name, ".")(0)) ' reference referenced workbook sheet named after it
        .Range("A1").Resize(.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
                            .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column) _
                    .Copy Destination:=Workbooks("MASTER.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1") ' copy and paste in one shot
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    .Close savechanges:=False 'Will NOT save changes
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    '''FUTURE CODE

End With

''GO TO NEXT FILE
SourceRow = SourceRow + 1 ' Move down 1 row for source sheet
```